# Determining if a user input field is empty

Tags: javascript

I've looked at some of the answers here but for some reason, I can't get this to work. I want the user to grade something and if they input nothing in the required field and press "Grade", I want for it to alert something.

```js
function Script() {
  var G = document.getElementById("gradevalue").value
  if (G == null || G == undefined) {
    window.alert("Please input a grade");
  }
}
```

```html
<label id="grade">|Please grade on a scale from 1 to 10 (10 is the best!)         
    <input id="gradevalue" type="text"; size="2"; maxlength="2">
    </label>
<input type="button" value="GRADE!" id="nota" onclick="Script()">
```

I'm very new at this, so please don't be too harsh.

Comment: You didn't check against the empty string? `G==""`

Comment: How about just checking for a false-like value? `if (!!G)`

Comment: Unrelated but remove the semicolons between the HTML attributes.

Comment: A blank input will be an empty string, not a null or undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you can simply check it like:

```
if (!Number(G)) {
   window.alert("Please input a grade");
}
```

this is going to be `true` if `G` is `null`, `undefined`, `''`, `0`, `false` and `NaN` and any strings that are not converted to numbers.

```js
function CheckGrade () {
  var G = document.getElementById("gradevalue").value;
  if(!Number(G)) {
    window.alert("Please input a grade");
  } else {
    //your code here, maybe some othe validation logic
  }
}
```

```html
<label id="grade">|Please grade on a scale from 1 to 10 (10 is the best!)         
<input id="gradevalue" type="number" min="1" max="10"/>
</label>
<input type="button" value="GRADE!" id="nota" onclick="CheckGrade()">
```

**UPDATE** Added a code sample and minor mistakes.

Comment: yes, tried it, but nothing happens when you press the "grade" button. I know, it should work, it's driving me crazy!

Comment: yes! it works now! I didn't know about the "!" before the variable. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Checking `!G || G == 0` seems to do the job:

```js
function Script() {
    var G = document.getElementById("gradevalue").value
    if(!G || G == 0) {
        window.alert("Please input a grade");
    }
}
```

```html
<label id="grade">|Please grade on a scale from 1 to 10 (10 is the best!)         
    <input id="gradevalue" type="text"; size="2"; maxlength="2">
</label>
<input type="button" value="GRADE!" id="nota" onclick="Script()">
```

Note that you may also want to check for > 11 values:

```
if (!G) {
    window.alert("Please input a grade");
} else if(G == 0 || G > 10) {
    window.alert("Please input a grade between 1 and 10");    
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you guys are awesome! I fine tuned the code according to your suggestions and it's perfect :)

Comment: @CristinaNeculai Glad I helped. Could you accept/upvote useful answers?

Answer (score 0):

You are also must there, in JavaScript you can just check if the variable has a value assigned to it, if it doesn't then the bool expression will be false. I have done a quick CodePen with the working code https://codepen.io/robdavis/pen/bRVxdm

```
function Script() {
  var g = document.getElementById("gradevalue").value

  if (!g) {
    window.alert("Please enter a Grade");
  }
}
```